# BMW 1 series f40 wing mirror indicator failure

Tags: bmw, indicators, mot, 1-series

really need some help with this as we’re £1000 down & still not fixed !
2020 f40 1 series BMW
Failed the mot as the driver side wing mirror glass smashed & indicator was not working, front & rear indicators working fine but flashing too fast.
We suspect it had been hit at some point.
Replaced the glass & light section - still no better
Checked fuses, when you press the hazards the front & rear indicators were fine , not flashing too fast like they do with the indicator stick.

Mechanic came out & replaced the whole wing mirror, glass & connecting electrics - still not working - he was unable to fix the problem but still charged £790 for the pleasure.
The problem is now worse at the whole driver side indicators are not working !
Auto electrician came out today thinking it may just need reprogramming - plugged it in & has no errors etc so nothing he could do.

Pleaseeeeee someone advise where we go from here. We’re stuck with a car with no MOT , majorly out of pocket & with a worse problem than before

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!